# How to use elemMatch in Springboot to query an element of an array such that the array has just one column and the column has no field name?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

The table I am having is of the following form

```
{ 
    "element_1": 1, 
    "element_2": 1,
    "elements":[
        "ele_1", "ele_2", "ele_3", "ele_4"
    ]
},
{ 
    "element_1":2, 
    "element_2":2, 
    "elements":[ 
        "ele_5", "ele_6", "ele_7", "ele_8"
    ]
},
{ 
    "element_1": 3,
    "element_2": 3,
    "elements": [ 
        "ele_9", "ele_10", "ele_11", "ele_12"
    ]
}
```

Over here I wanted to query out the document having the element `ele_1` in the `elements` field so that on using the java command

```java
Query query = new Query("Required Criteria");
```

the document which should get returned should be

```
{ 
    "element_1": 1, 
    "element_2": 1,
    "elements":[
        "ele_1", "ele_2", "ele_3", "ele_4"
    ]
}
```

I would like to mention again that the arrays in the field "elements" have **no field name** hence providing a key parameter while building the Criteria object is not possible. How to get the required result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply write :

```
Query query = new Query("{'elements' : 'ele_1'}");
```

You dont need `$elemMatch`